# Not understanding the row-key in Python API of Hbase

Tags: python, hbase

I have a hbase table (`customers`)  in the following form:

```
hbase(main):004:0> scan 'customers'

ROW                                                          COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                                                             
 4000001                                             column=customers_data:age, timestamp=1424123059769, value=55                                                                                            
 4000001                                             column=customers_data:firstname, timestamp=1424123059769, value=Kristina                                                                                
 4000001                                             column=customers_data:lastname, timestamp=1424123059769, value=Chung                                                                                    
 4000001                                             column=customers_data:profession, timestamp=1424123059769, value=Pilot
```

I tried to extract these data using python API http://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/:

```
import happybase


connection = happybase.Connection('localhost',autoconnect=False)


connection.open()


table = connection.table('customers')


print table.families()


row = table.row('ROW')


print row
```

It prints  `table.families()` as:

```
{'customers_data': {'block_cache_enabled': True,

  'bloom_filter_nb_hashes': 0,

  'bloom_filter_type': 'ROW',

  'bloom_filter_vector_size': 0,

  'compression': 'NONE',

  'in_memory': False,

  'max_versions': 1,

  'name': 'customers_data:',

  'time_to_live': 2147483647}}
```

But it prints  {}, nothing, in row. I am just confused about my understanding  row-key value in hbase table. Do have any suggestion  how to get  data from hbase table using python  API?.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rowkey is "4000001" not "ROW".